# Input needed for my program

Tags: c

i need to write a code with 
Given a input string encode it,by giving priority to first character of its kind

Input Format

input contains string with

Constraints

```
1 <= length <= 200
```

Output Format

we have to print the string in encoded format

```
Sample Input 0
abbcc

Sample Output 0
ab2c2

Sample Input 1
aAABbb

Sample Output 1
a3B3
```

heres my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 201
#define dif ('a'-'A')

int main() {
    char arr[N],res[N],lower[N];
    scanf("%s",arr);
    int index=0,cnt=0,i;
    for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        lower[i] = arr[i];
        if(arr[i]>='A'&&arr[i]<='Z')
            lower[i] += dif;
    }
    index = 0;
    res[cnt] = arr[0];
    cnt++;
    for(i=0;lower[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(lower[i]!=lower[i+1])
        {
            if(i+1-index!=1)
            {
                res[cnt] = i-index+1+48;
                cnt++;
            }
            res[cnt] = arr[i+1];
            cnt+=1;
            index = i+1;
        }
    }
    res[cnt] = '\0';
    printf("%s",res);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not working for some of inputs anybody there to help me with that?(i dont know the inputs because it is a question from a contest)
thank you .

Comment: Please rephrase your prose to improve readability. The first few lines are hard to understand, or (at least for me) not understandable at all.

Comment: Also, read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 201

int main() {
    char arr[N],res[N];
    int count,i,j;

    printf ("Enter alphabetic string:\n");
    fgets(arr, N, stdin);
    arr[strcspn(arr, "\n")] = 0;

    size_t len = strlen(arr);

    for (i = 0, j = 0, count = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (!isalpha(arr[i])) {
                    printf ("Invalid character <%c> in string %s\n", arr[i], arr);
                    return -1;
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                    res[j++] = arr[i];
                    continue;
            }
            if (tolower(arr[i]) == tolower(arr[i-1]))
                    count++;
            else {
                    if (count == 0) {
                            res[j++] = arr[i];
                    } else {
                            res[j++] = count + '0' + 1;
                            res[j++] = arr[i];
                            count = 0;
                    }
            }
    }

    if (count != 0)
            res[j++] = count + '0' + 1;
    res[j] = '\0';
    printf ("result : %s\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter alphabatic string:
abbcc
result : ab2c2

$ ./a.out
Enter alphabatic string:
aAABbb
result : a3B3

$ ./a.out
Enter alphabatic string:
rrrfVvVd
result : r3fV3d

$ ./a.out
Enter alphabatic string:
QQQaaaaeeeeeeeeeccFg
result : Q3a4e9c2Fg
```

Note that the program does not have a check over `count` value and if a character occurs in input string more than 9 times consecutively then the output you get will have some character instead of that character count in the output string. I am leaving it on you to add code to handle this specific condition.